# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen »ändern« und »verändern«?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, verb, meaning-in-context

Gibt es eigentlich einen Unterschied zwischen **»ändern«** und **»verändern«**?

Gibt es Situationen, für die man nur ***ändern*** oder nur ***verändern*** verwenden kann?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ändern" und "verändern" unterscheiden sich bezüglich Absicht, Grad der Änderung und zeitlicher Betonung. Im Prinzip kann man immer "ändern" oder "verändern" verwenden, man ändert (verändert?) damit allerdings immer wie die Aussage letztendlich aufgefasst wird.

Beispiele:

> Der Kurs des Schiffs wurde geändert.

Dies impliziert dass die Kursänderung beabsichtigt herbeigeführt wurde und betont damit den neuen Kurs. (Vielleicht will der Kapitän ein Unwetter umschiffen, oder ein Notfall an Bord erfordert einen Zwischenstopp)

> Der Kurs des Schiffs wurde verändert.

Hier ist die Implikation, dass die Kursänderung unbeabsichtigt herbeigeführt wurde (zumindest, unbeabsichtigt aus Sicht des Verantwortlichen). Dabei wird der alte Kurs betont, der ja anscheinend beabsichtigt war. (Eventuell war die Strömung zu stark und das Schiff ist deshalb vom Kurs abgekommen, oder ein Saboteur hat einen anderen Kurs veranlasst)

> Die Hose wurde geändert.

Hier ist das immer noch erkennbar die selbe Hose, allerdings mit Änderungen im Detail (z.B. kürzeren Beinen). Diese Änderungen (und damit der neue Zustand) sind der Fokus dieser Aussage, und man würde davon ausgehen, dass diese Änderungen so gewollt sind.

> Die Hose wurde verändert.

Entweder ist das eine komplett andere Hose ("Die Schaufensterpuppe hat jetzt eine andere Hose an"), oder die Hose ist nicht mehr als die ursprüngliche erkennbar weil die Änderungen einfach zu groß sind (z.B. wurde die Hose umgefärbt oder künstlerisch überarbeitet). Inwiefern dies beabsichtigt war ist kontextabhängig.

> Ich werde mich ändern.

Bei dieser Aussage hängt viel vom Kontext ab. Sicher ist hier nur, dass es eine Änderung geben wird, und dass das zukünftige Ich deshalb zumindest etwas anders sein wird. Wenn diese Änderung nicht geplant sein sollte ("Ich werde mich bessern"), so ist sie doch wenigstens vorhersehbar (z.B. Pubertät). Der Fokus liegt dabei auf dem zukünftigen Ich, das anders sein wird.

> Ich werde mich verändern.

Auch hier hängt einiges vom Kontext ab. Klar wird aber, dass diese Änderung(en) entweder nicht direkt gewollt sind (z.B. geändertes Aussehen bei einer Chemotherapie) oder dass diese Änderungen groß genug sein werden um das zukünftige Ich als komplett andere Person erscheinen zu lassen ("Du wirst mich nicht wiedererkennen"). Die Betonung liegt hier mehr auf dem momentanen Zustand des Ichs, der in der Zukunft so nicht mehr vorhanden sein wird.